# How to prevent the kernel from exiting when a LibraryLink function segfaults?

Tags: kernel, crash, librarylink

I do realize that this might be controversial, but I believe I have a real need for it this time.

If a process tries to access memory at a location it doesn't own, it will by default exit with a "segmentation fault" error.  LibraryLink functions run in the kernel process, so if they crash, the whole kernel crashes.  Mathematica is normally used interactively, so a kernel crash can be very unpleasant and lead to lost data ... (even if the front end doesn't crash and the notebook isn't lost).

**How can I install some sort of protection so that when my LibraryLink function crashes, the kernel would print a warning about potential inconsistent state, but instead of exiting *right away*, attempt to give the user an opportunity to save (`Export`) their work?**

---

**Why do I believe that this is possible?**  Because MATLAB does it and sometimes R does it.  [Here's the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbpdF.png) that MATLAB shows when a MEX function (equivalent of LibraryLink) crashes. Notice the Attempt to Continue button.

**Why do I want it?** I understand that the right solution is to just fix the crash. Or if that's really out of my control, then use MathLink and make it run in a separate process. But consider a situation like that of [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM).  It's a big LibraryLink project that can't be easily transferred to MathLink.  It's using a large and complex library I didn't write myself that can crash in unexpected situations.  That small window of opportunity for the user to save their work (when the kernel state is not completely corrupted) would really be a big improvement.  igraph is not particularly crashy, but it does crash more often than builtin Mathematica functions.

**What about catching SIGSEGV?** My understanding is that on Unix systems it's possible to install a handler for SIGSEGV.  Is this the right way to go?  I don't want to catch all crashes, only those ones that are localized to my library. Is this possible?  Doing a global modification to the kernel process seems like a bad idea.

Any solutions are going to be system-specific. I'm primarily interested in OS X solutions (but also Linux and Windows).

[Cross posted on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/581848?p_p_auth=5HoyUoCR)

Comment: It's completely possible that I am misunderstanding something and this is not possible (or really not a good idea) after all.  I don't know much about processes, signals, etc.   Any comments will be most appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the solution but I always wanted to try [Bruno Haible's libsigsegv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/) and see if it can be made to work. But I have no idea if it can be done but I am more on the pessimistic side for this one. Good luck!

Comment: `ParallelEvaluate[subkernel]` ?

Comment: @rhermans What I am looking for is how to prevent (or rather postpone) a kernel crash, not how to separate everything into a different process.

Comment: I was wondering if you got a chance to try out the libsigsegv?

Comment: @user21 It's on my todo list, but I haven't gotten that far yet

Comment: If you ever get to try it I'd be very interested in the result - positive or negative and I'd very much appreciate if could let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @user21 Sure, I'll send you an email!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?  I am attaching a bounty

Comment: @QuantumDot I do not think that this is an easy thing to do. I gave up on it. There are specific cases that are easier to handle, e.g. uncaught exceptions in C++. And you can use custom array classes that have a toggleable debug mode and do something more intelligent on overflow, such as throw an exception (which can then be caught)

Comment: @QuantumDot In case you didn't notice, there's an answer below now.  I can't play with it for one more week though.

Answer (score 6):

If we all agree that bad things still might happen, then here is a start. I have set up a small repository with the code:

- [Catching Segmentation faults in a Wolfram Library](https://github.com/halirutan/CatchingSegfaults)

It currently works only on Linux (I have only tested it there), but I'm sure it is extendable to other systems as well.

The core idea is simply to create a handler for the signals that might be sent and return with an error from the library instead of loosing the kernel completely.

The function that produces a segfault is

```c
static void do_segv() {
    int *segv;
    segv = 0;
    *segv = 1;
}
```

and within Mathematica, you can call the library function with an integer where 0 means "do no segfault catching" and all other values set up a signal handler, call the `do_segv` and return with an error.

I didn't even bother to write the signal handler myself but [stole it from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32799720/1078614). The whole function looks like this

```c
DLLEXPORT int catchSegfault(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    mint i = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    if (i == 0) {
        do_segv();
        return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
    } else {
        struct sigaction sa;

        memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sigaction));
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

        sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
        sa.sa_sigaction = handler;

        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

        if (setjmp(point) == 0) {
            do_segv();
            return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
        } else {
            return LIBRARY_MEMORY_ERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

It basically works because the signal handler

```c
static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *dont_care, void *dont_care_either) {
    longjmp(point, 1);
}
```

jumps back to the last `if` condition returning 1 for `setjmp` which evaluates the `else` return. So when `do_segv` gets a `SIGSEGV` the handler is called and the library function immediately returns with an error.

I hope this gives at least a start.

Ahh, yes, before I forget it. Big thanks to [Sasha](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/68/sakra) for his awesome [`cmake` plugin](https://github.com/sakra/FindMathematica) that lets you easily write library code in [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/).

Comment: Thanks! But I'm running into problems.  I tried this with `CreateLibrary[{"library.c"}, "library", 
 "TargetDirectory" -> NotebookDirectory[]]` then `f = LibraryFunctionLoad["library", 
  "catchSegfault", {Integer}, "Void"]` and function loads correctly.  But both `f[0]` and `f[1]` cause kernel crash.  Maybe I'm misusing it?

Comment: @QuantumDot On which OS are you working?

Comment: I should have said: I'm on Mac OS X 10.11.  I noticed you stated that you tested it on Linux; I guess I'll have to do a little research to figure out how to make it work on Windows and Mac OS X as well.

Comment: @QuantumDot A painless method would be to write the same code in a short `main` that you can test on a console. If it works there but doesn't work inside Mathematica, we have a problem.

Comment: Ok good idea: I just did it on my console now (making `catchSegfault` a `main`) , and found that your code works as intended:  `i=0` produces `Segmentation fault: 11` and `i=1` returns without trouble.  So I think there's a problem when running it from within Mathematica.

Comment: [This plugin](https://github.com/sakra/FindMathematica)? Can you link to it please?